# Paypal integration with paypal webservice in asp.net site

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

i never use any payment gateway still now....but now i need to integrate paypal for my cart. from where user can purchase multiple data and made the payment from paypal site for multiple item. i was searching how to integrate paypal into my website. i thought paypal must have webservice for payment integration. i search google for submitting multiple cart item data to paypal. i got the code but that was not very good solution

```
String url;
url= “https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?” ;
url+= “cmd=_xclick”;
url+= “&business=vikvish@yahoo.co.in”;
url+= “&item_name=Sample_testing”;
url+= “&amount=10.50″;
url+= “&quantity=2″;
url+= “&return=http://www.google.com”;
url += “&cancel_return=http://www.rediffmail.com”;
url+= “&currency_code=USD”;
Response.Redirect(url);
```

this way i dont want to send multiple cart data to paypal site.

another way here.

```
protected void btnPayPal_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)

{

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<html><head>");

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(

"</head><body onload='document.form1.submit()'>");

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(

"<form action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' " +

"name='form1' method='post'>");

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(

"<input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>");

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(

"<input type='hidden' name='business' " +

"value='bob@domain.com'>");

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(

"<input type='hidden' name='lc' value='US'>");

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(

"<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='Widget'>");

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(

"<input type='hidden' name='amount' value='100.00'>");

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(

"<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD'>

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(

"<input type='hidden' name='bn' " +

"value='PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest'>

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(

"<input type='image' " +

"src='https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif' " +

"border='0' name='submit' alt=''>");

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(

"<img alt='' border='0' " +

"src='https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif' " +

"width='1' height='1'>");

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</form>");

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</body></html>");

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

}

this way we are sending cart item data to paypal site from code behind.

i need to post my multiple cart item to paypal by paypal webservice.
so please tell me all the steps in detail from scratch. what i need to do.
do i need to create buyer & seller both account at paypal end. how to get the paypal web service url. i need sample paypal web service code for sending my multiple paypal cart item data to paypal. how test that is everything works fine. what is paypal sandbox url. do i need to give valid credit card no to sandbox url. if yes then how money will be back again after testing from sandbox url. please discuss all the points in detail & guide me with sample code in step-by-step with all stage like from account creation to web service usage for sending multiple cart data to paypal site. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PayPal has well defined and publicly available [SDKs](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index), in different platforms, for all their products.

It will serve you well to read their documentation and follow their documented API instructions instead of trying to cobble up a "workaround" - yes, you can easily do so (create workarounds for HTML forms), but you maybe missing out on security - e.g. in your code above, anybody can inspect and tamper with all your FORM POST values.

Comment: u said "in your code above, anybody can inspect and tamper with all your FORM POST values." so how to make secure.